# (Sqlite) How would I get the if statement to check all lines of my database?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Im making a simple login system, currently i am making a method which checks if the username entered already exists in the database if it does it returns true else it will return false. The code i have tried at the moment only checks the first line in the database and if i try entering below the first line that already exists in the database it will still return false. What can i do to fix this

````
 {
     string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/logindb.db"; 
     IDbConnection dbconn;
     dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
     dbconn.Open(); 
     IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
     string sqlQuery = "SELECT id,username, password " + "FROM user";
     dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
     IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
         string usernames = reader.GetString(1);
         string passwords = reader.GetString(2);
         
         if(Username == usernames )
         {
            return true;
           
         }
         else
         {
          return false;
         
         }
     } ```
````

Comment: Reading every record from the database is never a good idea (it works great when there are 10 users, but what about 10,000 users?).   Try googling SQL WHERE.  Also, if yours is a multi-user system, think what would happen if 2 users try to create an account of the same name at the same time, your check would pass for the first user, but fail when creating the 2nd account.   There are many reasons why you should not create your own login system.

Comment: I do understand this however the intent is only to have 5 users so it should not be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for an exact match.  Keep in mind that "Stan" does not equal "stan" nor does "Stan" = "Stan "

I agree, however, with Neil, in that you always want to limit your searches if possible using the WHERE clause.  It doesn't matter if you have 5 or 5000 records, that's just best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you find a match, set a bool to true and break out of the loop, then return the bool. If there are no matches then it will implicitly return false.

*do not use this as a model of a good authentication system, it is highly flawed*

```
bool found = false;

 while (reader.Read())
 {
     int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
     string usernames = reader.GetString(1);
     string passwords = reader.GetString(2);
     
     if(Username == usernames )
     {
        found = true;           
        break;
     }
 } 

 return found;
```

Comment: Instead of using a `bool` variable simply use `return true;` and `return false;` ;)

Comment: @derHugo, yes if you returned from within the loop, which is not how I demonstrated it. I try to avoid multiple places that return, it is a style choice.